# Websession invalidation not working from Spring Boot 2.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-session

I wanted to upgrade my Spring Webflux project from Spring Boot 2.0.1 to Spring Boot 2.0.3. In my project, my sessions are backed by Spring Session Data Redis. When upgrading the Spring Boot version, I noticed a websession invalidation problem from Spring Boot 2.0.2+.

In Spring Boot 2.0.1, I invalidated my sessions this way :

```
webSession.invalidate().subscribe();
```

This caused my current session to be destroyed, and a new one was generated with a new session ID, creation time, etc.

However, from Spring Boot 2.0.2, the same code doesn't seem to fully destroy the session. The current session information are just "cleared", and the same session ID is still used afterward. This is a problem because it causes a null pointer exception in *ReactiveRedisOperationsSessionRepository.class* :

```
private static final class SessionMapper implements Function<Map<String, Object>, MapSession> {
        private final String id;

        private SessionMapper(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public MapSession apply(Map<String, Object> map) {
            MapSession session = new MapSession(this.id);
            session.setCreationTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli((Long)map.get("creationTime")));
            session.setLastAccessedTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli((Long)map.get("lastAccessedTime")));
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(Duration.ofSeconds((long)(Integer)map.get("maxInactiveInterval")));
            map.forEach((name, value) -> {
                if (name.startsWith("sessionAttr:")) {
                    session.setAttribute(name.substring("sessionAttr:".length()), value);
                }

            });
            return session;
        }
    }
```

As session data are empty (no creation time, etc.), the following line raises a NPE:

```
session.setCreationTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli((Long)map.get("creationTime")));
```

Is it a bug or have I missed something new in Spring Boot 2.0.2+ regarding Spring Session?

**UPDATE**

To provide more information, I created a sample project reproducing the problem: https://github.com/adsanche/test-redis-session

This project contains a simple controller exposing two endpoints:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello(final WebSession webSession) {

        webSession.getAttributes().put("test", "TEST");

        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/invalidate")
    public String invalidate(final WebSession webSession) {

        webSession.invalidate().subscribe();

        return UrlBasedViewResolver.REDIRECT_URL_PREFIX + "/hello";
    }
}
```

**Behavior when running the project with Spring Boot 2.0.1**

- Go to the first endpoint: *http://localhost:8080/hello*
- State of the session in Redis:

[image: Sess]

We notice the session ID starting with 7546ff, and the session data containing the "test" attribute plus the default session information (creation/last access time, etc.).

- Go to the second endpoint: *http://localhost:8080/invalidate*

The current session is invalidated, and a redirection is performed on "/hello", where the test attribute is added in a new web session.

- State of the new session in Redis:

[image]

We notice the new session ID starting with ba7de, and the new session data still containing the test attribute plus the default session information.

Now, let's reproduce this scenario on the same project with Spring Boot 2.0.3.

**Behavior when running the project with Spring Boot 2.0.3**

- Go to the first endpoint: *http://localhost:8080/hello*
- State of the session in Redis:

[image]

We notice the session ID starting with 12d61, and the session data containing the "test" attribute plus the default session information (creation/last access time, etc.).

- Go to the second endpoint: *http://localhost:8080/invalidate*
- State of the new session in Redis:

[image]

We notice here that the same session ID is still used, but the session has been cleared even from its default information (creation date, etc.). So, when it is invoked again, a NPE is triggered in the reactive redis session repository in the *apply()* method at the place I mention in my original post:

[image]

Hope this sample project helps to find out if its a bug or an implementation problem on my side.

Comment: could you share a snippet of code showing where/in which context you're invalidating the session and explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I basically want to logout a user (no Spring Security involved as my login function just applies page content customization). I have a logout endpoint that invalidates the session (webSession.invalidate().subscribe()) and performs a redirection on the home page, but when the session is invoked again, it is still the old and invalidated one that is returned. I provided a sample project (https://github.com/adsanche/test-redis-session) and a scenario to illustrate my problem in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring Session's `SpringSessionWebSessionStore`, or more specifically, its internal `WebSession` implementation. The problem is that on `WebSession#invalidate` session is only cleared from the underlying session store, but not marked as invalid so the subsequent request processing still ends up using the same session id.

I've openend [gh-1114](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1114) to address this in Spring Session.

I believe you haven't experienced this previously i.e. with Spring Session `2.0.2.RELEASE` and below due to another bug in `SpringSessionWebSessionStore` that was addressed in `2.0.3.RELEASE` - see [gh-1039](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1039). This issue was about failing to update the `lastAccessedTime`, and once we fixed that the scenario you described started failing due to session for invalidated (and deleted) session id being saved again only with `lastAccessedTime` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and glad to hear that this is a known issue. I'll stick to Spring Boot 2.0.1 for the moment and hope it will be solved in a future release soon.

Comment: @Sancho I've fixed [gh-1114](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1114) in `master`. If you could give [`2.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`](https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/session/spring-session-core/2.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/) a try and confirm it fixes your problem that would be great.

Comment: I gave a try overloading the spring-session-core dependency with 2.0.5-BUILD-SNAPSHOT, and it fixes the problem. When invalidating the session, a new session ID is created afterward and the new session is filled with default session data (creation time, etc.). Can't wait to have the fix in the next release. Thanks for you quick action and your work on the framework.